# Using POI Jar for Android Application is resulting in Out of Memory error for bigger files

Tags: apache-poi

My need for POI jar was to just identify whether the Office file has an encrypted package name or not. For that I am instantiating the `POIFSFileSystem` with `FileInputStream`. As the API reads till the End of the file (EOF), the byte array when it is getting initialized, it is resulting in Out of memory Error. This is on Android but not on a DeskTop.

Any suggestion on how to identify a package name without reading till the EOF.

```
POIFSFileSystem poifsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
Entry entry = poifsFileSystem.getRoot().getEntry("EncryptedPackage");
```

I am looking for that entry in files that I am opening. I looked at the source code and found that the NPOIFSFileSystem class reads through all the blocks and then it fills in the propertyList. The code is interdependent. Without reading through the entire file, it doesn't seem to be possible to read the property list.

Any other library that can serve me the same purpose so that it can be used in a mobile application where memory is a concern.

Or any other suggestions

Comment: As per [the Apache POI docs, don't use an InputStream if you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream). That'll save you a chunk of memory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my case, I have to use the FileInputStream. Here is the good news. I tested until a 32 MB file and I am not facing any OOM error. For now I am good. When I posted this, I was testing with a specific word document, which seems to have been corrupted and is resulting in OOM error.